# Is it acceptable to create a feed for every page using Pubsubhubbub?

Tags: rss, publishing, ping

We have a setup that creates a "new" feed each time we add a page that has the URL: http://example.com/pubFeed.php?page=page_id

The final page_id parameter changes for each new page that we add. So essentially we create a new feed per page. And will end up 'creating' 1000s of feed URLs.

With our setup it's the most convenient way to go. So the question is, even though it's not conventional, would this still be acceptable?

Comment: Acceptable for what?

Comment: Accepted way to pinging SubHub, since we're going to be creating thousands of differents feeds

Comment: So each feed would only ever have one page in it?

Comment: Yes exactly, it's one feed per page

Comment: The reason that people subscribe to RSS feeds is generally to get notified about new content.   Are you planning change these pages on a regular basis and send out notification of that via RSS?

Comment: we have a consumer forum so sometimes certain pages change very often, but sometimes they remain the same. When a page would get updated we would update the same RSS feed, so we're not creating new RSS feeds for existing pages we would just update that one RSS feed which was created n the past (hopefully it's not too confusing).

Comment: Right, but why would you subscribe to RSS for a single page?   Would you get updates about new replies in the forum thread?

Comment: yes exactly, if you're subscribed to that one topic feed it will get updated when there's a new reply (we're running a consumer complaint forum).

Comment: That sounds fine from a user experience perspective, but I don't know anything about Pubsubhubbub.